# mongoose find and save not updating the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to find and modify and save back to the collection.
Here is what I have tried:

```
if(req.body.writer){
     MyModel.find({writer: req.body.oldname},function (err, data) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    data[i].writer= req.body.newName;
                    data[i].save()                    
                }
            });
}
```

why is this not updating the document? 
where is the problem lying? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update method :

```
if(req.body.writer && req.body.newName){
     MyModel.update(
        //search documents with old writer
        { writer : req.body.oldname},
        // set writer as newName
        { $set : { writer : req.body.newName} },
        {"multi": true},
        //check for error
        function (err) {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            else{
                res.status(200).send('updated successfully..');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: this is only updating the first occurrence. How can I update all matching documents?

Comment: You need to pass {"multi": true}  as third parameter. I have updated the answer, please check.